# how to get instagram photos with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, instagram-api

I am trying to show Instagram photos in my Ruby on Rails application. The following code works on my local machine but on my server in AWS it does not show the images.

At the time of making `data = JSON.parse file.read` does not seem to return any value on the server, but on my PC it shows the `JSON`. What could I be missing?

```
<%
require "open-uri"
photo_count = 10
begin
  file = open("https://www.instagram.com/#{@user.instagram}/?__a=1")
  data = JSON.parse file.read
%>
  <% data['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'].each do |instagram| %>
    <div class="col-xl-6 xd">
      <!-- Photo Box -->
      <% @caption = instagram['node']['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'].count > 0 ? instagram['node']['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'][0]['node']['text'] : "" %>
      <a href="<%=instagram['node']['display_url']%>" class="photo-box mfp-gallery" data-background-image="<%=instagram['node']['display_url']%>" data-toggle="lightbox" title="Instagram">
        <div class="photo-box-content">
          <span>Instagram</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% rescue => ex %>
<% end %>
```

Update:

When doing file.read on my local machine I can see that it shows me all the instagram user data in this way:

```
{"logging_page_id":"profilePage_31229027","show_suggested_profiles":false,"show_follow_dialog":false,"graphql":{"user":{"biography":"Inquiries to email@gmail.com\nAll images are under artist copyrights","blocked_by_viewer":false,"country_block":false,"external_url":"http://www.website.com/","external_url_linkshimmed":"https://l.instagram.com/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wrl ...
```

but on the server I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in client-root"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <title> Login • Instagram </title> <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex, noarchive"> <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default"> <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"> <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"> <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover"> <link rel="manifest" href="/data/manifest.json">
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: All of that is in a view file???

Comment: Seems Luice has PHP background @jvillian

Comment: @jvillian thats correct, all of that in the view file

Comment: That `rescue` block is rescuing everything, right? That's generally considered code smell because you swallow all errors and then end up having very-difficult-to-debug bugs, like the one you're having now. Also, no code in view, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a lot of requests, maybe Instagram has blocked your server to get images, your source is working, but the Instagram API has protection.

You can try to use an IPs proxy to get the images.

Comment: probably, how can I use an ip proxy on that server?

Comment: I tried to change the ip with a proxy and nothing, remains the same

Comment: I tested your source, and it works. Maybe you need a require for JSON.parse 

require 'json'

Comment: @LuisC Did you ever figure this out??

Comment: @WilliamHampshire yes, check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api